# How to make Pinterest pinit button

Tags: php, wordpress, pinterest

I am thinking to develop a plugin which creates Pinterest pinit button. I could not able to find the API for Pinterest Buttons. Can anybody tell how to find pinit button code?
Is pinterest providing API publicly?

Comment: You mean something like this: http://business.pinterest.com/widget-builder/#do_pin_it_button ? The href is easy to modify so you could easily make multiple buttons with custom links/descriptions etc.

Comment: Yes,can i append my own url from the link(code) which is created after  clicking the build it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=YOUR_PAGE_URl&amp;media=IMAGE_URL&amp;description=Spinach Artichoke Meatballs on MyRecipeMagic.com" count-layout="none" target="_blank" onclick="rewards('pin_it')" class="pin-it-button"><img border="0" title="Pin It" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

My best solution, i attach the  code  with other social share

```
<div class="si-share noborder clearfix">

<div>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=$AbsoluteLink" class="social-icon si-borderless si-facebook" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">
        <i class="icon-facebook"></i>
        <i class="icon-facebook"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="social-icon si-borderless si-twitter" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');return false;">
        <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
        <i class="icon-twitter"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="pinit" class="social-icon si-borderless si-pinterest" >
        <i class="icon-pinterest"></i>
        <i class="icon-pinterest"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=$AbsoluteLink" class="social-icon si-borderless si-gplus" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,'', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=500');return false;">
        <i class="icon-gplus"></i>
        <i class="icon-gplus"></i>
    </a>
</div>
<span style="float: right">Share :</span>
```

and relative javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pinit").click(function(){
        $("#pinmarklet").remove();
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
        e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');
        e.setAttribute('id','pinmarklet');
        e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e);
    });
});
```